# Making(programming) virtual drives on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-drive

Ahoy,

I'd like to mount a "virtual drive" myself on Windows XP, I guess using the windows API.

What I thought about would be like a server interface, meaning explorer.exe would send "queries", like, list directory, or get file through a pipe or whatever...

I know some programs do it, maybe not the way I think it is done, but what the heck,

if you know anything, enlighten me please!

Comment: This is a non-trivially difficult task.  (Either by shell namespace or as a real filesystem)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "virtual drive"? Do you mean like a VPC (.vhd) or VMWare Workstation (.vmdk) like virtual drive?

Comment: I mean something a user can explore using explorer, but which is made of data found on a network, and encrypted data, and all sorts of data actually... More on shell namespace please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom nodes to Explorer by writing a [Shell namespace extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144095.aspx).

Note that it will only show up in explorer; it would not be usable from other applications or file APIs like an ordinary disk.